# Guzzle unable to bypass cURL error 35: SSL connect error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, guzzle, guzzle6

Using Guzzle 6 I am attempting to communicate with an Https endpoint that uses a self-signed certificate.

I am instantiating my Client class as follows:

```
$authClient = new Client([
    'base_uri' => config('app.auth_uri'),
    'verify' => false
]);
```

And attempting a request:

```
$res = $this->authClient->request('POST', '/auth', [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'username' => 'RSA',
            'grant_type' => 'password'
        ]
    ]);
```

Here is the error I get:

```
cURL error 35: SSL connect error (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

According to the Guzzle docs I should have done enough to bypass the SSL error.

Answer (score 1):

After all that, it turns out my cURL library didn't support the TLS version used by the endpoint. It's a known problem on Centos 6.x servers which my Vagrant box was.

I updated my libcurl with the help of this guide:

[Update cURL library on Centos 6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-upgrade-curl-in-centos6)