# cURL error 35: SSL connect error with wp_remote_get() in third party API call not working

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am working on gravity form add-on for our CRM product in wordpress. I have used following code. I don't know why this response is occurring and tried a lot but no getting any hope for it. So, Please look at following output.

### CODE

```
<?php

$request = array(
    'headers' => $headers,
    'method'  => $method,
        'sslverify'=>false,
        'httpversion'=>'1.0',
        'AppAccessKey'=>'MyAccessKey ',
        'AppPrivateKey'=>'MyPrivateKey',
        'sessiontoken'=>'Mysessiontoken'
); 

$response = wp_remote_get($apiUrl, $request );


print_r($response);


?>
```

But i m getting following OUTPUT in response.

### OUTPUT

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [http_request_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => cURL error 35: SSL connect error
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384161/curl-error-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-to-api-rkd-reuters-com) are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411236/curl-error-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-to-api-mailgun) other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073404/curl-errno-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-to-secure-site443) wrt error 35, did you already read the answers there?

Comment: Maybe you should update curl library on server?
See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321794/guzzle-unable-to-bypass-curl-error-35-ssl-connect-error

Comment: Thanks ! But while I am using cURL then it gives me proper response data without any error. Why it happening this kind of issue with wp_remote_get()? may know reason if you know?